# Conflict issues with Prototype, jQuery and Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, prototypejs

I am working on a PHP project that was originally using prototype and jQuery to do all of its javascript/ajax magic but was using flash for its charting.

At the point of me looking into it the project was using the following versions

- PHP 5.5.9
- Prototype - 1.5.0
- jQuery - 1.11.0

(OLD versions I know )

But they both (js libs) were working with each other no problem.

So I am tasked with upgrading the versions and improving the charting and of course first port of call is Highcharts/Highstocks. I installed version 3.0.7 of highcharts.

So firstly I upgrade the project to PHP 7.2.24. The version of jquery I was using, 1.11.0 seemed to work fine with highcharts but not with prototype. So I needed to upgrade the version of prototype I was using.

I worked out that the version this gets fixed is in prototype version 1.6.1

Amazing! So I now have a working application using jquery 1.11.0 and prototype 1.6.1 BUT...

As soon as I use anything in prototype for example

```
new Draggable()
```

I get the following errors in the chrome console

```
prototype.js:709 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Element.setOpacity (effects.js:69)
    at HTMLDivElement._methodized [as setOpacity] (prototype.js:338)
    at Function.setStyle (prototype.js:2214)
    at Element.setOpacity (effects.js:69)
    at HTMLDivElement._methodized [as setOpacity] (prototype.js:338)
    at Function.setStyle (prototype.js:2214)
    at Element.setOpacity (effects.js:69)
    at HTMLDivElement._methodized [as setOpacity] (prototype.js:338)
    at Function.setStyle (prototype.js:2214)
    at Element.setOpacity (effects.js:69)
```

I have searched the internet high and low and tried every combination of prototype version with jquery version and just cant seem to get this to work. It fills the console with thousands of errors, but funnily enough actually still works, which is weird.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do or where I can look please?

Comment: 1. You have used the Highcharts tag, but it seems that your problem is not related to using this library. 2. `Then the first problem I encountered was that highcharts needs a new version of jquery,` - that's not true, Highcharts works with the jQuery 1.6+ https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/compatibility

Comment: @Sebastian Wędzel - thanks for your response. Sorry yes you are correct, I have just put my jquery version back to its original version of 1.11.0 and that is working fine with highcharts BUT still throwing the issue as specified. I will adjust my question and tags.

Comment: @Ander Kew, no worries, Highcharts tag brought me here, that's why I pointed out on it. Unfortunately, I am not able to help you more because I don't know `prototypejs` at all. I hope that the community will show up with some solution for you.

Comment: @Sebastian Wędzel - Quick question though before we right out highcharts issue. I just played around a bit more. If I keep my prototype and jquery versions to 1.5 & 1.11.0 include highstocks.js there is no error but as soon as I create a chart I get the error Uncaught TypeError: (d || "").split(...).reduce(...).join is not a function. Seeing as highcharts can work with other version jquery this makes me think its the version of prototype that is the problem no? BTW to get prototype and jquery to work in the same page correctly I had to set jquery to non conflict mode: $j = jQuery.noConflict();

Comment: @Ander Kew, I have seen that you use the really old one version of Highcharts - 3.0.7 - I am afraid that this version of the Highstock doesn't exist - https://www.highcharts.com/blog/changelog/, so I tried to reproduce the issue using the previous version with different versions of jQuery, but I cannot see any conflict... The prototype might create this issue. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4qmj30rz/

Comment: @Sebastian Wędzel - Oh wow i didnt realize highcharts is at version 8 already. I got the version by using composer as my depedency manager so that must be the last version that is supported through composer. Also when did it become a paid for library?

Comment: @Sebastian Wędzel - sorry my bad in my latest testing I am actually using v8.2 of highstocks including the following link in my code - https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js

Comment: `Also when did it become a paid for library?` - to be honest, I am not sure, but as I started work with the 5th version it was already paid. ` I am actually using v8.2 of highstocks including the following link in my code` is the issue still occurs? Are you able to reproduce it on some online editor?

Comment: @Sebastian Wędzel  - after more investigation I have pin pointed the problem to the following javascript call: Effect.Pulsate() - this is a scriptaculous method, commenting that out and my errors go away. How weird is that. I will try investigate as to why or just move away from scriptaculous and use jquery instead.